# Blocking RSS Brute Force 1.9

Tags: 301-redirect, rss, http-status-403

I noticed this weekend that someone was pounding on /rss/catalog/notifystock/ trying to brute force the admin credentials. I've added a line to the nginx vhost.d conf that returns 403 when you attempt to visit /rss/catalog/notifystock/ effectively blocking this attack. I've also blocked /rss/order/new and /rss/catalog/review as I discovered they were vulnerable during my research.

When I check the nginx access log I still see them pounding away. The access log shows it is returning a 301 instead of the 403 they should be seeing. Any ideas on why I might be seeing the 301?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need /rss?

If not, just do this in your `nginx server {}` block

```
location ~ ^/index.php/?rss/ {
    deny all;
}
location ~ ^/rss/ {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of RSS feeds that the client is using.
The server block in nginx.conf in commented out and the conf.d and vhost.d conf files are being used.

Comment: in that case, it might make sense to block all /rss except the url's your client is using?